# Telegram bot - get all channels and groups' ids inside which bot is

Tags: telegram-bot

I would like to get all channels and groups' ids inside which bot is.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't do that. You should have your update listener save the updates inside a database and then query them with chat_id.

Comment: @AliPadida Thank you so much